# how to pass date format from controller to directive using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

how to pass variable "$scope.dateformat" to "format" in 
           directive.Please 
           let me know if any examples are available or suggested.
           Please suggest me more examples on this.

```
     $scope.dateformat ="yyyy-mm-dd";

      menuModule.directive("datepicker", function(){
      return {
        restrict: "EAC", 
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            "ngModel": "="
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            $(elem).datepicker({
               format: "yyyy-mm-dd", // Above $scope.dateformat should be 
                                             //   called here
            }).on("changeDate", function(e){
                return scope.$apply(function(){
                    console.log(attr);
                    return scope.ngModel = e.format();
                });
            });

            return scope.$watch("ngModel", function(newValue){
                $(elem).datepicker("update", newValue);
            });
             }
          };
         });
```

Comment: you will get dateformat in scope in link function..put console.log(scope) in link fn in that you will find your scoped data

Comment: So this dateFormat is declared where? It looks to be outside of the directive, is it declared in the page controller where the directive resides?

Comment: dateformat is inside the controller and the directive is outside the controller

Comment: first controller should load and after that directive should load

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a $scope variable in the global scope (I hope).

### First approach

If this dataFormat is meant as a global configuration, you could register it in angular as a constant like this:

```
menuModule.constant('DATE_FORMAT', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

and then inject it in your directive:

```
menuModule.directive("datepicker", function(DATE_FORMAT){
    return {
        restrict: "EAC", 
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            "ngModel": "="
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            $(elem).datepicker({
                format: DATE_FORMAT
        });

        // .. rest is omitted
    };
});
```

### Second approach

If you want the format to be passed to the directive through the attributes (and thus make it available in the scope) you'll add it as a scope binding like this:

```
menuModule.directive("datepicker", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "EAC", 
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            "ngModel": "=",
            "dateFormat": "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            $(elem).datepicker({
                format: scope.dateFormat
        });

        // .. rest is omitted
    };
});
```

then whenever you use the directive, you can pass the format like this:

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"></datepicker>
```

or if it comes from a controller

```
<datepicker date-format="{{$ctrl.dateFormat}}"></datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Directive`

```
    scope: {
        "format": "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
        $(elem).datepicker({
           format: scope.format
        })
    }
```

`HTML`

```
     <datepicker format="dateformat"></datepicker>
```